# Syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".txt")

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I'm getting an error

> Syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".txt")

at the `if` statement line. I check `words_in_line` by doing `echo $words_in_line` and it outputs numbers, so I don't understand why I'm getting this error. How do I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    
#Outputs the lines that match wordcount range specified by min, $1, and max, $2
function get_correct_lines_in_file() {
     while read line ; do
        words_in_line=$( echo "$line" | wc -w );
        if [[ words_in_line -ge $1 ]] && [[ words_in_line -le $2 ]]; then #ERROR HERE
            echo "$line" >> MARBLES.txt
        fi
    done < $1
}

#Check if $1 and $2 arguments exists- are NOT NULL
if [[ "$1" != "" ]] && [[ "$2" != "" ]]; then
    for i in ${*:3} 
    do
        #If is a file you can read 
        if [[ -r $i && -f $i ]]; then
            echo "$i exists and is readable"
            get_correct_lines_in_file "$i"
        #If file doesn't exist
        elif [[ ! -f $i ]]; then
            echo $i >> FAILED.log
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: Are `$1` and `$2` known to be numeric? Could you modify your code to demonstrate (ideally, *prove*) that they are?

Comment: BTW, just as an aside, it's rather inefficient to open `MARBLES.txt` for output every time you want to write a line to it and re-close it after writing that one line. It'd be more efficient to move the `>> MARBLES.txt` to the end of the loop, thus redirecting it only once for the whole loop, not once per `echo`.

Comment: Actually, `< $1` means your `$1` **has to be** a filename, not a numeric value.

Comment: `$1` is a filename. i added the rest of my code

Comment: Ahh. You're confusing `$1` the argument to your function with `$1` the argument to your script.

Comment: ohh okay so how do i reference the 1st argument in my func `get_correct_lines_in_file()`

Comment: BTW, `words_in_line=$( echo "$line" | wc -w )` is really slow to run. You don't want to put it in a loop, which is why I switched it out with a native-bash implementation in my answer.

Comment: ...I *am* assuming that you don't care about keeping your input file's specific whitespace (ie. that it won't be a problem to switch tabs to spaces) in my answer, but that's straightforward enough to fix if it's a problem.

Comment: BTW, `${*:3}` is quite buggy. `"${@:3}"` is more correct. To demonstrate the difference, consider: `set -- one two "third argument" "fourth argument" "fifth argument"`, and then compare the output of `printf '%s\n' "${@:3}"` to the output of `printf '%s\n' ${*:3}`

Comment: The problem isn't with `$words_in_line`, the problem is that `$1` is not a number, it's the filename.

Comment: WHen you're debugging a shell script, the most useful tool is putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script. It will then show every statement as it's executed, with the variables expanded. Then you can see where the incorrect value is coming from.

Comment: That said, personally, I'd assign `$1` and `$2` to named variables, shift them off your argument list, and then just iterate over the rest of that list (`min=$1; shift; max=$1; shift; for i; do echo "Processing lines in $i with between $min and $max words" >&2; done`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your minimum and maximum values to be accessible in your function, you need to pass them through. Consider accepting *three* arguments in your function, and explicitly passing the function's arguments through:

```
get_correct_lines_in_file() {
     local -a words
     while read -r -a words ; do
        words_in_line=${#words[@]};
        if (( words_in_line >= $2 )) && (( words_in_line <= $3 )); then
            printf '%s\n' "${words[*]}"
        fi
    done <"$1" >>MARBLES.txt
}
```

...and later, passing the filename to be the function's `$1`, the script's `$1` to be the function's `$2`, and the script's `$2` to be the function's `$3`:

```
get_correct_lines_in_file "$i" "$1" "$2"
```